# How do you uninstall and remove Firefox in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firefox, uninstall, 18.04

I am trying to remove/uninstall Firefox from Ubuntu 18.04.  I have used `sudo apt-get purge firefox`. I have also deleted all the files I was told to delete for Firefox, but it is still there and opens.I don't like the new Firefox and don't want it.  How can I remove it totally?

It isn't listed in the Software Apps, where you install or remove apps.

Comment: Did you install it manually ?

Comment: What do `apt policy firefox` and `locate firefox-bin` show?

Comment: maybe installed with snap. try `snap remove firefox`

Comment: Firefox came with the new upgrade.  I didn't have it in the earlier version.  When checking on the Snap software installer, it doesn't show up as installed.  It's like it is embedded into 18.04 somehow.  But on the internet list of browsers that are there, it shows up and it opens when it is clicked on.

Comment: What about "sudo apt autoremove firefox"?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge *package name*
```

That is how I typically remove programs and applications

Answer (score -1):

Try this if the normal approach isn't working.

```bash
sudo rm -fr /opt/firefox
sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox/firefox_backup /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
sudo apt remove firefox
```