# Stop the Ubuntu updater from nagging about Firefox English Language pack even after uninstalling Firefox

Tags: updates, firefox

I have run `sudo apt purge firefox`, and I have gone through all of the /.config files, etc., and Software Updater is still asking me daily if I want to install the "English Language Pack for Firefox".

I don't have Firefox installed. How can I stop the updater from asking to update something on a program that doesn't exist?

Output of `dpkg -l | grep firefox`:

```
ii  firefox-locale-en                          88.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2        amd64        English language pack for Firefox
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you uninstall and remove Firefox in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039258/how-do-you-uninstall-and-remove-firefox-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @24601 This does not seem to be a duplicate of the question you suggested. It is about removing the language pack, not Firefox itself.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the English language pack for Firefox with

```
sudo apt remove firefox-locale-en
```

Then it won't show up in the updates.

Comment: I have followed your instruction on removing the language pack. It was removed according to the terminal output. I'll know tomorrow if this worked. I'm sure it did, there shouldn't be anything in to update since it showed removed. Thank you for your help, and especially for as quickly as all of you responded to my question. Take care and be well.

Comment: Quick question though, If I used the "Purge" command in terminal, and then went though and removed what I thought was all of the config files and others that were marked either Firefox or Mozilla from the directories, why would the language pack remain?

Comment: @JamesReece because "purge" does not uninstall dependencies. The language pack is a separate package that is installed as a dependency for main Firefox package. To uninstall package and its dependencies, use `sudo apt-get remove <packagename> --autoremove` (you may also add `--purge` parameter to purge instead of remove). Or later after removing package use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove all dependencies that are no more used by any package.

Comment: Terrific information. You are greatly appreciated. Take care and be well.